# Использование полей объекта в другом классе

Tags: java, swing

Существует класс Player

```
public class Player {


//---------get


public int getSword() {
    return sword;
}

public int getPike() {
    return pike;
}

public int getBow() {
    return bow;
}

//--------------------------------set


public void setSword(int sword) {
    this.sword = sword;
}

public void setPike(int pike) {
    this.pike = pike;
}

public void setBow(int bow) {
    this.bow = bow;
}

//------------------------------fields

private int sword = 0;
private int pike = 0;
private int bow = 0;
```

Есть класс Enemy

```
 private int bow;

private int sword;
private int pike;



//------------------

public int getBow() {
    return bow;
}

public int getSword() {
    return sword;
}

public int getPike() {
    return pike;
}

//----------------------


public void setBow(int bow) {
    this.bow = bow;
}

public void setSword(int sword) {
    this.sword = sword;
}

public void setPike(int pike) {
    this.pike = pike;
}
```

Есть класс Frame, в котором предыдущие классы реализованы:

```
public class Frame extends MainFrame {

private JLabel swords;
private JLabel pike;
private JLabel bow;


private JLabel eswords;
private JLabel epike;
private JLabel ebow;


private JButton addAtt;

 Enemy ene = new Enemy();
Player player = new Player();
Attack att = new Attack();


public Frame() {
    super();

    //--------------

    eswords = new JLabel("swords:" + ene.getSword() );
    epike = new JLabel("pike:" + ene.getPike());
    ebow = new JLabel("archers:" + ene.getBow());


    JToolBar tq = new JToolBar(SwingConstants.VERTICAL);

    tq.add(eswords);
    tq.add(epike);
    tq.add(ebow);

    tq.setFloatable(false);

    add(tq, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //------------

    swords = new JLabel("swords:" + play.getSword() );
    pike = new JLabel("pike:" + play.getPike());
    bow = new JLabel("archers:" + play.getBow());

    JToolBar tz = new JToolBar(SwingConstants.VERTICAL);

    tz.add(swords);
    tz.add(pike);
    tz.add(bow);

    tz.setFloatable(false);

    add(tz, BorderLayout.WEST);

    //---------------------------

    addAtt= new JButton("Battle");



    JToolBar tx = new JToolBar(SwingConstants.VERTICAL);

    tx.add(addAtt);



    tx.setFloatable(false);

    add(tx, BorderLayout.EAST);

addVB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            att.Battle();
            updateCountVB();
            updateCountAB();

        }
    });

}

private void updateCountVB() {
    ebow.setText("archers:" + ene.getBow());
    epike.setText("pike:" + ene.getPike());
    eswords.setText("swords:" + ene.getSword());
 }

private void updateCountAB() {
    bow.setText("archers:" + play.getBow());
    pike.setText("pike:" + play.getPike());
    swords.setText("swords:" + play.getSword());

}
```

И есть класс Attack, так сказать, проблемный :)

```
public class Attack  {
Player play;
Enemy ene;

private int playerarmy = (play.getSwords()*10) + (play.getPike()*7)+(play.getBow()*5)

private int enemyarmy = (ene.getSwords()*10) + (ene.getPike()*7)+(ene.getBow()*5)   


public void Battle(){
if(playerarmy>enemyarme)
{...}
....




}
```

---

Вообщем вопрос: в классе Attack мне нужно использовать значения объектов play и ene. Как мне посоветовали написать: final Player play и final Enemy ene и использовать конструктор; но тогда обращение к методам гет и сет, через эти объекты дают ошибку инициализации. Если без final, то при работе программы вылетает ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> но тогда обращение к методам гет и сет, через эти объекты дают ошибку инициализации

ну наверное потому и выдают, что у вас `play` и `ene` не инициализированы - вы в классе `Attack` нигде не инициализируете эти поля, несмотря на то, что создаете сами экземпляры перед созданием `Attack`. Можете, например, передавать их в конструктор класса `Attack`,  либо инициализировать их уже в нем, либо сделать для этих полей сеттеры и вызывать их - вариантов достаточно.

А вообще у вас тут есть довольно странный код: классы `Player` и `Enemy` выглядят совершенно идентичными. Отсюда возникает вопрос - зачем нужен класс `Enemy`,  если его легко заменить классом `Player`?

Comment: public Attack(Player play, Enemy ene) {
this.play = play;
this.ene = ene;
playerarmy = (play.getSwords()*10) + (play.getPike()*7)+(play.getBow()*5);
enemyarmy = (ene.getSwords()*10) + (ene.getPike()*7)+(ene.getBow()*5)}

Так через конструктор?)